# Avgerage Time Complexity of a sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I have a treesort function which performs two distinct tasks, each with its own time complexity. I figured out the avg. case time complexity of the two tasks but how do I find the overall complexity of the algorithm.

For example the algorithm takes in a random list of "n" keys x:

```
Sort(x):
    Insert(x):
        #Time complexity of O(nLog(n))
    Traverse(x):
        #Time complexity of O(n)
```

Do I just add the two complexities together to give me O(n + nLog(n)) or do I take the dominant task (in this case Insert) and end up with an overall complexity of O(nLog(n))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*or do I take the dominant task (in this case Insert) and end up with an over complexity of O(nLog(n))*
That's right.  As `n` grows, first element in `O(n + nLog(n))` sum will become less and less significant. Thus, for sufficiently large `n`, its contribution can be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

In a simple case like this,

```
O((n) + (n log(n)) = O(n + n log(n))
                  = O(n (log(n) + 1))
                  = O(n log(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the dominant one.

The whole idea of measuring complexity this way is based on the assumption that you want to know what happens with large `n`s.

So if you have a polynomial, you can discard all but the highest order element, if you have a logarithm, you can ignore the base and so on.

In everyday practice however, these differences may start to matter, so it's sometimes good to have a more precise picture of your algorithm's complexity, even down to the level where you assign different weights to different operations.

(Returning to your original questions, assuming you're using base 2 logarithms, at `n=1048576`, the difference between `n+n*logn` and `n*logn` is around 5%, which is probably not really worth worrying about.)